# React: first time, undefined error, but after reload, it success

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I make web application with react, redux, redux-thunk, react-router-dom v4.

I have created a component that loads a post.

But at the beginning, the value is undefined, and the value is loaded successfully when I reload page.

Why will not the value come in at first?

App.js:

```
...
{this.props.posts.map((post, index) => (
          <div key={index} style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}>
            <Link to={`/post/${post._id}`}>{post.title}</Link>
            <br />
            <span>{post.content}</span>
            <br />
            <span>{post.author}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
...
```

Post.js:

```
class Post extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getPostDetailFetch(this.props.match.params.id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col xs="12">
            <h1>{this.props.post.title}</h1>
          </Col>
          <Col xs="12">
            <h3>{this.props.post.author}</h3>
           <Col xs="12">
            <p>{this.props.post.content}</p>
           </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
       );
    }
  }
 ...
```

index.js:

```
import { Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import history from "./history";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
     <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/post/:id" component={Post} />
     </div>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
   document.getElementById("root")
  );
```

Comment: `this.props.posts` is undefined?

Comment: @Justcode yes. it is undefined in first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work because you are fetching posts in an asynchronous way. So, in the first render they are undefined. Just use conditional rendering:

```
...
{!!this.props.posts.length && this.props.posts.map((post, index) => (
          <div key={index} style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}>
            <Link to={`/post/${post._id}`}>{post.title}</Link>
            <br />
            <span>{post.content}</span>
            <br />
            <span>{post.author}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
...
```

The same problem goes for `Post.js`. So, you should also do the conditional rendering there.

```
render() {
    if ( !this.props.post) {
        return <div>No post!</div>
    }

    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col xs="12">
            <h1>{this.props.post.title}</h1>
          </Col>
          <Col xs="12">
            <h3>{this.props.post.author}</h3>
           <Col xs="12">
            <p>{this.props.post.content}</p>
           </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
       );
    }
```

Also, if the post detail is not different then in the posts array, I think you don't need to do a fetch again here. Just change your logic and with `id` get the post detail from store somehow.

Comment: But it still undefined in first time. after reload, it works.

Comment: Why do you reload if you only trying to get the posts? What does happen when you first time you open this page? Are you doing any `POST` operation to backend before trying this?

Comment: Also, where do you get this `undefined` error? `App.js` or `Post.js`?

Comment: @devserkan error is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined".  And, Post.js is error component. Also, console.log(this.props.post), it is undefined.

Comment: localhost/api/post/id is successfully load data.

Comment: Then, the same problem is in the `Post.js` since `post` is undefined when you first render it. After fetching you get it. Do the conditional rendering again and see if solves your problem. Also, if the `post` detail is not different then in the `posts` array, I think you don't need to do a fetch again there. Just change the logic and with `id` get the post detail from store somehow.

Comment: @devserkan Thank you sir! Your answer has been a great help. By the way, Why does 'if (!this.props.post)' work and it works?

Comment: You are welcome. I did not quite understand your question. If you are asking how `!this.props.post` works we are checking if there is a `post`, if not returning something else since it is undefined and if we try to render it there will be an error.

Comment: @devserkan I wonder why it works by putting that 'if (!this.props.post) ~~'.I don't speak English, well. Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176914/discussion-between-devserkan-and-ko-ma).